# Unexpected dark patch in Cycles render

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hello, could you help me please?

Do you have any idea what's this black spot? (It's extra low-res, just a test render. In viewport, everything looks normal. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, maybe overlapping faces, either in the same object, or 2 objects overlapping?

Comment: Yes! This is certaily it. When I move the longer grass "layer" particles slightly up, the black spot dissapears. However, this is not the best solution, because this causes change of colors and weird blending.
Should I delete the top faces? But then my grass will be gone... 

Comment: Yes, I did it. But experience problems anyways. 
Nevermind, thank you. At least I am on the right path to solve the issue now :))

Comment: If for some reason you have another object that is the emitter and you don't want it to be visible you can disable its visibility in the Particle panel > Render > disable Show Emitter